# Acute triangle $\triangle ABC$ has $(\sin A - 2 \sin 2B) = 2 - 2 \cos 2B$ Find the range of $\frac{\sin B + \sin C}{\sin A}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Angles in acute triangle $\triangle ABC$ has $(\sin A - 2 \sin 2B) \tan A = 2 - 2 \cos 2B$

Find the range of $$\frac{\sin B + \sin C}{\sin A}$$

We can prove that $\frac{a^2}{bc} = 4$ through some tedious trigonometric computations

Let $\frac{b+c}{a} = k$, then
$1 > \cos A = \frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$, and we plug in  $\frac{a^2}{bc} = 4$, and we might be able to find the range of $k$ somehow? But I can't finish and the computation seems daunting. I am also not sure if $\cos A <1$ condition is too loose.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the relation between the sides you have posited. Are you certain it's correct? The solution to this problem seems to be intractable without calculus.

Comment: aplogoies I missed an $\tan A$  @DinosaurEgg

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are very close.

You have established $\frac {\sin B + \sin C} {\sin A} = \frac {b+c}a$ using the Law of Sines.

From $\frac {a^2}{bc} = 4$ we obtain $a^2 = 4bc$ and $bc = \frac{a^2}4$.

Now:

\begin{align}
1 &> \cos A\\ &= \frac {b^2 + c^2 - a^2}{2bc}\\
&=\frac {b^2 + c^2 - 4bc}{2bc}\\
&=\frac {b^2 + 2bc + c^2 - 6bc}{2bc}\\
&=\frac {(b+c)^2}{a^2/2}-6\\
&=2k^2-3\\
k^2& < 2
\end{align}

Comment: apologies I missed an $\tan A$

Comment: That does not change my solution as I used your result from $\frac {a^2}{bc} =4$ onwards.

Comment: Well the thing is I am not sure if $\cos A <1$ condition is too loose.

Comment: Good point. We also need $\cos A > 0$ since the triangle is acute.